# How to set placeholders on UITableView rows?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a UITableView with 3 empty rows. The user can select which text to add to each row by touching it. However I would like to set some placeholders in grey, instead of having an empty row.

Something like: **"Select it"**

Comment: I dont really understand.  What do the row have in them? are they labels? input boxes? A screenshot might really help explain your situation.

Comment: Ya, I'm using UITableViewCell cell.textLabel.text = "My Text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using UITableviewCell's with UITextField's in them.   If so, in Interface Builder (or the Storyboard) you need to select the label in the cell and then find the placeholder property.  Fill in whatever text that you want it to display when the text field's are empty.

If you created them programatically,then you set the placeholder like this:

```
myTextfield.placeholder = @"Select it";
```

Comment: Thanks. No I'm using: UITableViewCell cell.textLabel.text = "My Text" and I can't see placeholder property for UILabel

Comment: okay, then you can just change the color to grey like this: 'cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];' and set the text like you do above.  Change the color back when you add the new text.